# Rep recalc questions won't stop: put a banner to user's profiles

Tags: feature-request

There are a lot of measures proposed for "the time of recalc".  Put banner on SO, increase amount of close votes, put banner on meta (already done) etc

However, there's a small flaw in this logic: there's no "time of recalc".  Recalc is an event that changes rep once and forever.  When the "time of recalc" ends, and all banners are removed, some users will start asking the question about their reputation again.

I think that it would be useful to put banners to userinfo pages of currently registered users, the banners disappearing after user sees them once.  Userinfo is a particularly good place, because

- it doesn't draw unnecessary attention of newcomers (they don't see it)
- it doesn't mingle those who's aware of the issue (banners are private, and disappear after fist read)
- it will prevent user from asking such questions since the first place he goes to check his rep is his profile.

Worth doing?

Comment: Or one of those notification popups.

Comment: Just do whatever's working for SU and SF.

Comment: @random: Not have users who care?

Comment: @random - you mean discourage people from using the site?  I thought the recalc already was.  :-)

Comment: The not caring option. That sounds good. @mmy

Comment: This is a better idea than putting a banner on the main page, where lots of people will ask a question because they don't understand what it means.

Comment: Just make it one of those standard pop-up banners (you know, like the one that shows up at the top to welcome you to Meta Stack Overflow for the first time, or notify you that someone's posted an answer to the question you're working on). Those always get my attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only going to be a few days of madness, then tapering off to maybe another question about rep change once a day (as usual).

Be patient, this too shall pass.

Comment: I disagree. Some people don't check SO everyday. (Unfortunately, I am not one of those so-disciplined!)

Answer (score 2):

I support this idea (and disagree with Pollyanna), for the following reason:

The influx of questions we're seeing now comes from *regulars*. Who supposedly read the blog and/or visit Meta on a regular basis anyway.

What we are yet to see is the influx of questions from the long tail: people who visit SOFU only every other day, only once a week, only every other week, only once a month, and so forth. This is a *much larger* user group, and its members are even *less likely* to learn about the recalc from either the blog or Meta.