# Where did my rep go?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The global reputation recalc of March 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010)

I had about 1000 rep points two weeks ago. Now I'm suddenly down to around 700. What gives?

Comment: Actually, lowering reputation when away for a while might not be too bad. ;-)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43504/rep-recalc-questions-wont-stop-put-a-banner-to-users-profiles

Comment: You must have left the door open, so it trickled away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the great rep recalc! [The global reputation recalc of March 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010)

Comment: omg... i'm gonna kill someone

Comment: Nah, don't do that. Just answer more questions!

Answer (score 8):

Unicorns eat rep.

Comment: Why didn't mine? I must be lucky then.

Comment: Sadly enough, the real answer has less votes than the Unicorns. What is this world coming to?

Comment: It's OK -- I don't mind. I upvoted this answer :-)

Comment: lol............................